# Devices No Longer Supported | When releasing app on google playstore

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-play-console, google-developers-console, mobile-devices

1. [Devices No Longer Supported](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTVl9.jpg)

[Change Minimum API 16 TO API 19](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWWx7.jpg)

## Main Problem

See Image "Devices No Longer Supported" Is that Ok ..?

## What i did

See Image "Change Minimum API 16 TO API 19"  Because Minimum API Level is 19 in Unity2020.1.0

i also downloaded API level 16-17 on SDK .?

## For Knowledge

is it possible to get Minimum API Level 16 in Unity 2020.1.0 ..?
or is this normal ..? Mean its ok to upload with Minimum API Level 19 ..?
is there any way to get all devices support ..?
Any suggestion , Help , Advice ..? Thank you in advance

Comment: If the Minimum API Level vor unity2020 is API 19, then there is probably no way around setting the Minimum API Level for your app to API 19. If you want to support older devices, you may need to use an older version of unity. But keep in mind, API 19 was released in Oct. 2013. And according to Google there are less than 2% of devices with API < 19. So really don't think, requiring at least API 19 should be a big problem.

Answer (score 3):

It is ok that some older devices out of support, as they no longer support some features of **Unity2020.1.0+**.
For ***Google Play***, it just warns you about the issue, just leave it if you do not consider about the older devices. But, if you still want to support some devices with API 16+, then just download **Unity 2019.2+** from [archieve](https://unity3d.com/ru/get-unity/download/archive).
https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/AndroidSdkVersions.html

Answer (score 0):

Its your app so it is OK to cut support to lower APIs but,

Usually you want to keep support for the widest number of devices if possible since then more people can download your app. Now if your app uses newer features that are only available in unity 2020.1.0+  you might want to either find a different in game solution or simply drop support. On your developper dashboard somewhere you should be able to find out how many users for each API downloaded your game. So you can check if they make up any significant amount of users.

I work at a company that makes a lot of kids games so we usually try and keep as much support for older devices as possible since kids tend to use hand me downs.

Now keep in mind that API 19 -> Kit kat is over 7 year old already. So keeping compatibiliy for devices even older than that may not be worth the trouble. They might already have a hard time running your game.